# How can I find my mail merged InDesign document?

Tags: mail-merge, adobe-indesign

I created a mail merge using InDesign, and it looked like it went through all of the records but (1) I can't find the option to export to pdf and (2) I can't find the merged file anywhere on my system *at all*.  Where is it?

Comment: Start a search and narrow down the creation date to the current day, or to the past few hours. But this question surely, surely doesn't belong on SO. It may get migrated to Superuser.com soon.

Comment: Start by narrowing down where it isn't